# scroll top when clicking on a div, then scroll bottom if scroll is on top

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, jquery-animate, scrolltop

I'm using a Jquery code on my website. when clicking on a div (.bottom), my page scrolls to top. it works perfectly fine, here is my code :

```
function scroll_cartouche(){
    $('.bottom').click(function() {
  $("html, body").animate({ scrollTop: $(document).height() }, 500);
});
```

now that my page has scrolled top top, I would like when clicking on the .bottom div again, to scroll to bottom (return at the initial position)

here is the code I tried but I have a bug :

```
function scroll_cartouche(){
    $(window).scroll(function () {
        if ($(this).scrollTop() != 0) {
            $('.bottom').click(function() {
                $("html, body").animate({ scrollTop: $(document).height() }, 500);
            });
        } else {
            $('.bottom').click(function() {
            $("html, body").animate({ scrollTop: 0 }, 500);
            });
        }
    });
}
```

can anybody help me with this ?
thanks a lot,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

do something like

```
$('.bottom').click(function() {
    if ($(window).scrollTop() == 0) {
        $("html, body").animate({ scrollTop: $(document).height() }, 500);
    } else {
        $("html, body").animate({ scrollTop: 0 }, 500);
    }
});
```

Comment: thanks @cforcloud, works fine... I just had to inverse the conditions ! thanks a llot

Comment: ... and click shouldn't be added inside $(window).scroll function